# Loading http content in https page

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hi I have a page which is **https** and in the same page i have a `<iframe>` tag which is basically has to load the **http** content from the 3rd party server(amazon server).
But the problem here is its not loading the content into `<iframe>` as it is http, What is the work around for this problem?
Any solution greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is this question related to java?

Comment: There is no silver bullet here.  The content in the iFrame must be https also.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS for second page in iFrame